# How to use Vertx Pump() to connect a filestream to Kafka producer stream?

Tags: apache-kafka, vert.x

I am reading a large file using Java readStream. And I want to stream it to a Kafka topic. Currently, I am using the KafkawriteStream method to stream each ProducerRecord. It is working fine.

But recently, I read about the vertx Pump() method which is a much better and cleaner way to achieve it. Unfortunately, I am new to vertx and didn't find much document online related to my goal.

How to use Vertx Pump() method to connect File readstream to kafkaWriteStream? Suggestions are also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

`Pump` is an utility provided by *Vert.x* that models the back-pressure capability allowing.

The utility class should be instantiated instantiated with a `ReadStream` and a `WriteStream` then started:

```java
Pump.pump(readStream, kafkawriteStream).start();
```

Note that the `Pump` is not started by default and can be started and stopped as many times as you want.